# Removing ^ symbol from end of string

Tags: php, trim

I've looked up quite a few methods for this, but I'm not seeing any of them working correctly, I wonder if it has something to do with the specific symbol I am trying to remove: `^`

`$current` currently = blah,blah,blah^ - I want to remove `^`

```
rtrim($current, "^");
```

Above is what I have attempted first, but it does not remove the trailing `^`

Neither does `substr` with an arg of -1.

Is it something to do with this specific symbol?

Comment: Please provide output from `var_dump($current);` Your string might contain additional hidden stuff.

Comment: Both your statements indicate that you have a trailing whitespace. so `^` is not the last symbol (nothing to trim) and substr with -1 removes that whitespace. (Oh, and what Jim said, if you are using the substr method in the same way)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rtrim($current, "^");
```

returns the modified string. You'll need to use the returned value:

```
$current = rtrim($current, "^");
```

See [here](http://codepad.org/jg1un43q)

Comment: better phrasing: "returns the modified string".